# How to move post title right to the thumbnail on front page

Tags: css, wordpress

What is the css code to move post title right to the thumbnail on front page. Please help my website is 
http://www.avjtrickz.com

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could always just apply `float: right` to `.post-title` like I've done here in Chrome inspector: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hj514whsy27h4vr/Screenshot%202016-11-06%2010.55.48.jpg?dl=0

Comment: Thanks for your advice.I added that code but it doesn't worked. The screenshot you provided is exactly I want. please help

Answer (score 0):

Change the line 569 of your CSS to

```
.post-title, .post-title a {
    color: #1e73be;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: I used that code but it only moves right and not inline with thumbnail. Now website look like this http://www.avjtrickz.com how to make thumbnail and post title in same line. Please help. Thank you for your advice

Comment: OK add these 2 rules to your .post-title on line 554 `float:right;max-width:70%;` Note: you have to take care of responsiveness yourself. This is what I see: http://prntscr.com/d3uf8t

Comment: Great! It worked. but now the problem is the post title float right on single post page also. I only want this to my home page. Thanks for your advice

Comment: Then Use the float and max-width in a new rule like: `body.home .post-title,body.archive .post-title{ float:right; max-width:70%;}`

Comment: Added that code. But only first post title on home page is floating right. We are almost there. please help

Comment: Please help me. What to do now?

Comment: It seems to be working for me. http://prntscr.com/d48y6q Why don't you make the changes and then see on the live server if there was an issue, and then proceed?

Comment: You are awesome bro. Now the problem solved. Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0):

I added a parent div to your thumbnail and title, swap their position(image first then title) and added some css

```css
.classyoulike {
display:inline-table;
}
.wp-post-image {
display: table-cell;
min-width: 120px;
}
.post-title {
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:top;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-header">
<div class="classyoulike">
 <img width="120" height="120" src="http://i2.wp.com/www.avjtrickz.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/avjtrickz-deals-of-the-day-.jpg.jpg?resize=120%2C120" class="alignleft wp-post-image" alt="avjtrickz-deals-of-the-day-.jpg.jpg" srcset="http://i2.wp.com/www.avjtrickz.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/avjtrickz-deals-of-the-day-.jpg.jpg?w=1773 1773w, http://i2.wp.com/www.avjtrickz.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/avjtrickz-deals-of-the-day-.jpg.jpg?resize=120%2C120 120w, http://i2.wp.com/www.avjtrickz.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/avjtrickz-deals-of-the-day-.jpg.jpg?resize=500%2C500 500w, http://i2.wp.com/www.avjtrickz.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/avjtrickz-deals-of-the-day-.jpg.jpg?resize=1024%2C1024 1024w, http://i2.wp.com/www.avjtrickz.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/avjtrickz-deals-of-the-day-.jpg.jpg?resize=450%2C450 450w, http://i2.wp.com/www.avjtrickz.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/avjtrickz-deals-of-the-day-.jpg.jpg?resize=60%2C60 60w, http://i2.wp.com/www.avjtrickz.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/avjtrickz-deals-of-the-day-.jpg.jpg?resize=45%2C45 45w, http://i2.wp.com/www.avjtrickz.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/avjtrickz-deals-of-the-day-.jpg.jpg?resize=800%2C800 800w, http://i2.wp.com/www.avjtrickz.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/avjtrickz-deals-of-the-day-.jpg.jpg?resize=600%2C600 600w" sizes="(max-width: 120px) 100vw, 120px" data-wp-pid="1733" >
<h2 class="post-title"><a href="http://www.avjtrickz.com/deals-of-the-dayexclusive-shopping-deals-august-19/" rel="bookmark" title="Ambrane Power Bank P-2000 (20,800mAh ) white at 60% OFF (*November 4*)">Ambrane Power Bank P-2000 (20,800mAh ) white at 60% OFF (*November 4*)</a></h2>
  </div>
  </div>
```